# is it possible to display a "satellite" map with kivy mapview?

Tags: kivy, folium, mapview

I would like to integrate a satellite map in my kivy app.
[expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HqRQS.png)

After some research, I don't think it's possible with kivy's mapview module (there's only the default mode).
[default mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O04IN.jpg)

I've also seen that the folium package allows you to create custom web maps, but I can't figure out how to display them directly in my kivy app.

If anyone has a solution, please let me know.
Thanks in advance :)